# Live video information

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to fetch some sort of flag from YouTube when a channel goes live?

For example, when a YouTube channel starts broadcasting live, I need to be able to fetch that information and use it. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use search.list then set the [**`eventType`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) parameter to **`live`**.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCXswCcAMb5bvEUIDEzXFGYg&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API_KEY]
```

Sample code snippet:

```
// Sample php code for search.list

function searchListLiveEvents($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->search->listSearch(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

searchListLiveEvents($service,
    'snippet', 
    array('eventType' => 'live', 'maxResults' => 25, 'q' => 'news', 'type' => 'video'));
```

Hope this helps.